# Javascript toLocaleDateString converting nulls to 12/31/1969

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-date

Javasript `toLocalDateString` is converting my null dates in API to 12/31/1969.
How can I prevent this behavior, and just show nulls? Or do I have to write conditional statements each time?

```
const formatDate = (dateInput: string) => {
  const formattedDate = new Date(dateInput).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  return formattedDate;
};


<TableCell align="right">
  {customerBodyView?.enrollmentDate == null
    ? ""
    : formatDate(customerBodyView?.enrollmentDate)}
</TableCell>
```

[image]

Comment: It was the winter of '69!

Comment: `How can I prevent this behavior, and just show nulls?` By not passing `null` to `new Date`.

Comment: `new Date(dateInput)` is always going to be some non-null date. Just add the check in the function instead? `const formatDate = (dateInput: string) => !!dateInput ? new Date(dateInput).toLocaleDateString("en-US") : "";`

Comment: That date in the console is the day before the unix epoch.

Comment: `const formatDate = (dateInput: string) => dateInput == null? null: new Date(dateInput).toLocaleDateString("en-US");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const formatDate = (dateInput) => {
    if (isNaN(Date.parse(dateInput))) {
        return null;
    }

    // success
    return new Date(dateInput).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
};

console.log(formatDate("12/12/2023")); // 12/12/2023
console.log(formatDate(null)); // null
console.log(formatDate("null")); // null
console.log(formatDate("")); // null
console.log(formatDate(undefined)); // null
```

Comment: hi, I gave points, feel free to upvote my question also, thanks